# Pandas - Creating multiple columns similar to pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say my data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'], 'line': ['sunday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'monday', 'monday', 'tuesday'],
               'group': ['1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1'], 'value': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b']})

    color   group   line    value
0   red       1     sunday   a
1   blue      1     sunday   b
2   green     2     monday   a
3   red       1     monday   c
4   blue      1     monday   a
5   blue      1    tuesday   b
```

Essentially, what I want is to get a list of lines for each color. For instance, I want the color red to show each line and value associated with it in its own column. The trick is that I also want to show other lines associated with colors from the same group. The corresponding values for those would be 'not eligible'. Thus I want my output to look like this:

```
    color   line_1  line_1_value    line_2  line_2_value    line_3     line_3_value
0   red     sunday       a          monday       c          tuesday    not eligible
1   blue    sunday       b          monday       a          tuesday         b
2   green   monday       c
```

There are some ~50,000 unique 'colors' that I need to do this for. I'm sure it's something relatively simple, but I don't possess the knowledge or skillset yet to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the column you don't need and add a column to get a unique subindex per color:

```
df = df.drop('group', axis=1)
df['index_by_color'] = df.groupby('color').cumcount()

   color     line value  index_by_color
0    red   sunday     a               0
1   blue   sunday     b               0
2  green   monday     a               0
3    red   monday     c               1
4   blue   monday     a               1
5   blue  tuesday     b               2
```

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get the orientation of data you want:

```
df.pivot_table(index='color', columns=['index_by_color'], aggfunc=lambda x:x.iloc[0])

                  line                  value
index_by_color       0       1        2     0     1     2
color
blue            sunday  monday  tuesday     b     a     b
green           monday    None     None     a  None  None
red             sunday  monday     None     a     c  None
```

The thing about `aggfunc=lambda x:x.iloc[0]` is to reduce the non-numeric pivoted data as a specific value, and the first element of the subframe is enough as per the unicity of your data structure.

Reorder the column hierachical index:

```
 res = res.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)

                  line value    line value     line value
index_by_color       0     0       1     1        2     2
color
blue            sunday     b  monday     a  tuesday     b
green           monday     a    None  None     None  None
red             sunday     a  monday     c     None  None
```

The remaining parts are trivial cleanup depending on the exact presentation you need, like `cumcount()+1` if you need to start numbering at 1 instead of 0, write/flatten the column names as you want `res.columns =['_'.join([l0, str(l1)]) for l0,l1 in res.columns]` or equivalent, etc.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for; however, it doesn't take into account lines that are associated with another color in the group. So Line_2 for 'red' should show tuesday and the corresponding value should show 'not eligible'

Comment: Amend you dataframe as a first step by adding 'not eligible' in the value column for each group, then drop group and go on the algorithm above. The key idea is to prepare your dataframe with all you need inside before applying the pivot. Do you forsee the logic here?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to add the additional records to the end of my dataframe. Rolled it all into one function for future purposes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a merge on two pivoted dfs with column name handling:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('color').cumcount() + 1

pvt1 = df.pivot(columns='count', index='color', values='line').reset_index().fillna('')
pvt1.columns = ['color'] + ['line_'+str(c) for c in pvt1.columns[1:]]

pvt2 = df.pivot(columns='count', index='color', values='value').reset_index().fillna('')
pvt2.columns = ['color'] + ['line_'+str(c)+'_value' for c in pvt2.columns[1:]]

pvtdf = pd.merge(pvt1, pvt2, on=['color'])
pvtdf = pvtdf[[c for c in sorted(pvtdf.columns)]]

#    color  line_1 line_1_value  line_2 line_2_value   line_3 line_3_value
# 0   blue  sunday            b  monday            a  tuesday            b
# 1  green  monday            a                                           
# 2    red  sunday            a  monday            c
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for; however, it doesn't take into account lines that are associated with another color in the group. So Line_3 for 'red' should show tuesday and the corresponding value should show 'not eligible'.